# Airflow retry of multiple tasks as a group

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I have a group of tasks that should run as a unit, in the sense if any of the tasks from the group fail, the whole group should be marked as failed.

I want to be able to retry the group when it has failed.

For example, I have a DAG with these tasks:

```
taskA >> (taskB >> taskC) >> taskD
```

I want to say that `(taskB >> taskC)` is a group.

If either `taskB` or `taskC` fails, I want to be able to rerun the whole group `(taskB >> taskC)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a two parts question.

First, In Airflow downstream task can not effect upstream task. Assuming structure of:

```
taskA >> taskB >> taskC >> taskD
```

then if `taskB` is successful and `taskC` failed. it can not change the state of `taskB` to failed.

Second, clearing (rerun) a TaskGroup is a feature that currently is not available. There is an open feature request for it in Airflow repo. You can view it in this [link](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/14529).

Comment: is it possible to restart/clear upstream task? I have SparkKubernetesOperator >> SparkKubernetesSensor and sensor is the one retrying/failing but actually I want to retry operator task.